# fastest way to refer to vector in Armadillo library

Tags: c++, vector, armadillo

I am using Armadillo for linear algebra. I setup a pretty big vector (at least 35000000 elements). I have another vector of length half of the big vector. I am using the fftw to do the fourier transform on the big vector but the first half of the data is copied from the small vector as below

```
#include <armadillo>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include "fftw3.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main(void)
{
  arma::Col<double> v1, v2;
  v1.resize(35000000);
  v2.resize(17500000);
  // initialize v2
  for (int i=0; i<4096; i++) // repeat 4096 times
  {
    v1.rows(0, 17500000) = v2;
    fftw_complex* in = reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(v1.colptr(0));
    fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(35000000, in, in, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_MEASURE);
    v2 = v1.rows(0, 175000000);
  }
}
```

this code is pretty slow because we need to copy the elemenets from v2 to v1 and backward. Is that anyway to have v1's element refer to the v2 instead of copy?

Comment: Maybe look at [sub-matrix views](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat) ?

Comment: Do you alter v2 after copying v1.rows?

Comment: Actually, v2 is where I store my result, but I will use v1 in the calculation and only the first half will be saved back to v2. After v2 get updated, it will be copied to the first half of the v1 and repeat the same process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve, but
you can get the pointer to the memory used by the vector (or matrix) via the [.memptr()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#memptr) function. This pointer can then be used, along with an offset, to create a new vector (or matrix) which uses external/auxiliary memory through dedicated [vector constructors](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#adv_constructors_col) and [matrix constructors](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#adv_constructors_mat).

For example:

```
vec v1(35000000);

vec v2(v1.memptr(), 17500000, false); // v2 will now share memory with v1
```

Incidentally, don't use the [.resize()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#resize_member) function with Armadillo vectors and matrices unless you really mean to preserve existing data. Use [.set_size()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#set_size) instead, which is much faster.

Comment: It seems that almost like what I am looking for. But as my understanding, now v2 is pointing to the first half of v1, so the first half elements in v1 is sharing memory with v2, right? So if I modify any element with index less than 17500000 in v1, will the corresponding elements be changed in v2 too?

Comment: Hi mtall, thanks for your suggestion. That's really what I am looking for. But I came to a new question when using the similar technique for a matrix. For example, I have a 5x5 matrix M1, I want a M2 matrix which is 3x5 sharing the same memory of M1 so M2 will refer to the first 3 rows. I did about the same thing as your did like mat m1(5,5); mat m2(m1.memptr(), 3,5, false, false); but this will make m2 refer to the first few columns instead. I think it is due to column-orient issue. How can I solve that?

Comment: The memory layout in Armadillo matrices follows that of BLAS and LAPACK. In other words, data is stored column by column. As such, it would be relatively inefficient to access elements in a row.  I suggest you modify your algorithm to work on entire columns instead of entire rows. Matrix transposes could help here (eg. do processing on each column, and then transpose the matrix to get the answer in a row by row format).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It is a big headache to modify the code then, this is just a small portion of a couple-thousands-line code :(

Comment: One more question. If I write vec v2(v1.memptr(), 17500000, false); the code go without any problem. But if I do vec v2; v2=vec(v1.memptr(), 17500000, false); It does compile but it won't refer to the v1. What I want the second case instead for reason, is there any workaround? Thanks